# How to import function in React with Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to import a function in a class, and the function is located in an other file.
I have types.ts with :

```
export castToString = () => {//implementation}
```

And in my file form.tsx, I want to import this function :

```
import {castToString } from '../types.ts'
```

To use this function, I call it like this :

```
castToString ()
```

But it doesn't work, an idea ? Thank you

Comment: what if you try import without brackets around? I believe that's only applicable if exported in brackets too.

Comment: Remove .ts from the import and the declaration should be `export const castToString =  ...`

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir you should make an answer out of that comment

Comment: @toskv you are right, but I just wanted to get a bit of confirmation the poster did not miscopy the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove .ts from the import statement (you will be importing the resulting JS not the TS and you should not specify the extension in either case). Also the declaration should be `export const castToString = ...`